# How much overhead does using MiniProfiler's Step() IDisposable add?

Tags: performance, mvc-mini-profiler

I'd like to use MiniProfiler from time to time to profile my code, but I don't want to branch off and keep re-introducing it; I'd like to leave it in there and just remove the `@MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes()` call from my layout template when I'm not using it.  However, my code would still look like this:

```
using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("Generate events index view model")) {
    _thisStep = MiniProfiler.Current.Step("Check query string");
    int pageIndex = 0;
    // Do check...
    _thisStep.Dispose();

    // Do other stuff...
}
```

How much overhead would leaving those `Step`s in there and disposing them cause?  Is there a way to tell MiniProfiler I'm not using it so that `Step` basically does nothing, but I can still leave it in my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as your `MiniProfiler` instance is null (i.e. you never call `MiniProfiler.Start()`), the `Step()` extension method will return null.  The only overhead at this point is the `using` statement, which is negligible.  Think of it as an extra `if (false)` statement that has to execute.

I would advise against the syntax you're using where you store the `IDispoable` outside of a `using` block, because you don't get automatic null checking on the `.Dispose()` call, e.g.

```
_thisStep = MiniProfiler.Current.Step("Check query string");

// if you do it this way, you will have to manually check for null every time
if (_thisStep != null) {
    _thisStep.Dispose();
}
```

The way I usually work is to only profile once per method - if I need another step, I have to extract the code into another method, e.g.

```
public EventsIndexViewModel GetViewModel() 
{
    using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("Generate events index view model")) 
    {
        var pageIndex = GetPageIndex();
    }
}

private int GetPageIndex()
{
    using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("GetPageIndex")) 
    {
        // Do check... return result...
    }
}
```

This has the added benefit of keeping my methods small :)

If you're on .NET 4.5, you can take advantage of the [`CallerFilePathAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute.aspx) and use [this `.StepHere()` helper method](https://gist.github.com/dixon/5491269) I put into our Stack Overflow code, which avoids having to name every `Step()` call!

Comment: "I would advise against the syntax you're using where you store the IDispoable outside of a using block, because you don't get automatic null checking on the .Dispose() call" ... which is why I actually use a `DisposeIfNotNull()` extension method I created.  The example just uses the standard method.  :-)

Comment: In a couple of places in our views, we actually do pass around the Step... I'll have to add that extension method, good idea!